r8126 driver re-install necessary for every Kernel update?
I'm about to install a Realtek RTL8126 5G PCIe Ethernet card.
This requires the r8126 module, which was introduced in Kernel 6.10.
Currently Ubuntu Noble is on Kernel 6.8 and from what I understand 6.10 isn't available yet.
There's however the possibility to install the Realtek driver, which contains an autorun.sh that builds and loads the r8126 module on older Kernels.
My question: do I need to run this script manually after every 6.8.x Kernel update?
Or is this done automatically?

Try it and see.If installing your driver requires a build in the current kernel,  and is signed by the current kernel, it will probably require a build in the next kernel.

Alas, you need to run the script for each kernel update: each kernel version and revision has its own modules folder (you can find them in /lib/modules) so the module needs to be rebuilt from sources.
